# Closed Form Solution for MLE parameter defining Linear Combination of two multivariate normal distributions

Tags: optimization, multivariate-normal-distribution, gaussian-mixture-distribution, generalized-least-squares, constrained-optimization

I have one set of $n$ observations which can be described as a single vector sampled from a multivariate normal distribution of the following form:

$$
(1-\lambda)\mathbb{I}_n + \lambda \Sigma_{n}
$$

where the values of the covariance matrix, $\Sigma_{n}$, are completely known to us and scaled to have 1s along the diagonal.  For context, we can measure the physical distance between the points in our network/graph and we have a model to convert those distances to covariance values.

So literally everything is known except the value of the parameter $\lambda$ which tells us how much the covariance between our $n$ observations is determined by their closeness in space versus just random white noise.  I need to find the maximum likelihood value of $\lambda$.  I'm really hoping that such a simple scenario will have a closed form solution.

If there isn't, then what I need most is an algorithm that always converges on the correct answer even when bounds exist. Here $\lambda$ is bounded in $[0,1]$.  A major problem I've been having with more complicated versions of this model is that all these optimization methods either get stuck at a boundary or worse: `nlminb`,`L-BFGS-B`,`bobyqa`,`cobyla`,`Rvmmin`,`hjn`,`MBO`. (granted, these have all been in multiple parameter settings... is it even possible to get "stuck" at a bound without it being the correct answer when there is just one dimension in the search space?)

Comment: Not a proof, but as a sanity check consider $n=1$.

You have a single observation $x_1$ from a normal distribution of the form $N(0,1-\lambda + \lambda \sigma^2)$ where $\sigma^2$ is given, and you want the MLE estimate of $\lambda$.  Well we know that the MLE estimate of the variance of the distribution is $x_1^2$.  So you are trying to solve $1-\lambda + \lambda \sigma^2 = x_1^2$.  This is not always possible when $\lambda \in [0,1]$, and if not the optimal parameter is likely to be on the boundary.

Comment: So I think your approach is "dead in the water".

Comment: 2 attempts to throw out a "life line": 1) sorry for the confusion, but the boundary is allowed to be an answer, I just don't want it to be given as answer by an optimization algorithm when it isn't.  2) The covariance matrix is designed to have 1s along the entire diagonal, so for a 1-D case Sigma^2, 1−λ+λσ2 simplifies to 1-λ+λ*1=1. So all Lambda values are equally likely... so maybe the approach is dead in the water... ayy! ...
3) What if I change the approach to find all values of Lambda which max

Comment: 3) What if I change the approach to find all values of Lambda which maximize the likelihood?  I guess for the 1-D case: λ=Any value is a closed form solution i guess.

Comment: Given that the diagonals of $(1-\lambda)\mathbb{I} + \lambda\Sigma$ always equal $1$, your MLE of $\lambda$ will be based on the sample covariances relative to the off-diagonal elements of $\Sigma$, and it seems plausible to me that a unique MLE exists.  Consider the edge case $n=2$, where you have $s_{ij}^2$ and $\sigma_{ij}^2$; $\hat{\lambda} = \min(1, s_{ij}^2 / \sigma_{ij}^2)$.

Comment: ... where $i=1, j=2$ or vice versa, to clear up the notation.